# Open new form on same position as closed one (visual basic)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Currently I have the following:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    Button2.Click
    Form2.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

However, when I start the program and open the new form by clicking `Button2`, the new form opens not in the same position as the first form, but in some other position. So, how would I go about opening `Form2` in the same position as the closed `Form1` (or `Me`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the form's Load event to put it wherever you want it.  Preferable over using StartPosition.Manual, you can be sure that DPI virtualization and AutoScaleMode don't get in the way.  Like this:

```
    Dim bounds = Me.Bounds
    Dim frm As New Form2
    AddHandler frm.Load, Sub() frm.Bounds = bounds
    frm.Show()
    Me.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for!